# Vue - Component that accepts a nested component

Tags: vue.js

I would like to have a component that can have another component placed into it. I'm struggling to find how this can be achieved.

If I pass a component in it doesn't get displayed. I'm assuming I need to specify it in the component however I can't find how in the documentation.

E.g.

```
<component-that-allows-nesting>
  <nested-component/>
</component-that-allows-nesting>
```

What needs to be added to my component to allow it to accept a nested component?

Comment: Use [slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html).

Comment: That's it thank you! Should I delete the question or do you want to answer it? It could be worthwhile for anybody else as I struggled to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Vuejs support nested component like Base Component and you can use it. if you want send data from parent component to child component you can use props.

for example

```
//parent-component

<form>
<base-input />
<base-button>
add form
</base-button>
</form>


//child-component
//BaseInput.vue
<input type="text" placeholder="userName" />

//BaseButton.vue
<button @click="submitForm" >

<slot></slot>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for vue3 carousel.

- You should import nested component
- You should add this component in components
- Use it as nested component

> ```
> <template>
>   <carousel :items-to-show="1.5">
>     <slide v-for="slide in 10" :key="slide">
>       {{ slide }}
>     </slide>
>   </carousel>
> </template>
>
> <script>
> import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue3-carousel';
>
> export default {
>   name: 'App',
>   components: {
>     Carousel,
>     Slide,
>   },
> };
> </script>
> ```